# Bootstrap com loop

Tags: php, table

Boa noite pessoa!!

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Estou tentando fazer uma tabela zebrada mas as linhas não estão ficando de cores diferentes, cinza e branco. Eu tenho um while no código, utilizando php.

```
      <div class="container" id="container">
    <h2>Ambientes Monitorados de <?php echo $nome_equipe?></h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Ambiente</th>
          <th>Solução</th>
          <th>Criação</th>
          <th>Ultima Atualização</th>
          <th>Criador</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
  <?php $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nome_ambiente, solucao_ambiente, dt_criacao_ambiente, dt_last_update_ambiente, nome_equipe FROM tb_ambientes LEFT JOIN tb_equipes ON tb_ambientes.id_equipe = tb_equipes.id_equipe WHERE id_user = '$id_user'");
    while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  echo "<tbody>";
  echo "<tr><td>" . $exibe["nome_ambiente"] . "</td><td>" . $exibe["solucao_ambiente"] . "</td><td>" . $exibe["dt_criacao_ambiente"] . "</td><td>" . $exibe["dt_last_update_ambiente"] . "</td><td>" . $nome_user . "</td></tr>";
  }
  echo "</tbody>"
        . "</table>"
        . "</div>";
  ?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue me ajudar a identificar aonde está o erro??

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está repetindo o `<tbody>` dentro do while, com isso a classe não terá o efeito esperado porque a tabela terá vários `<tbody>` com apenas 1 linha.

Coloque o `echo "<tbody>";` antes do while:

```
<?php $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nome_ambiente, solucao_ambiente, dt_criacao_ambiente, dt_last_update_ambiente, nome_equipe FROM tb_ambientes LEFT JOIN tb_equipes ON tb_ambientes.id_equipe = tb_equipes.id_equipe WHERE id_user = '$id_user'");
  echo "<tbody>"; // ANTES DO WHILE
  while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
      echo "<tr><td>" . $exibe["nome_ambiente"] . "</td><td>" . $exibe["solucao_ambiente"] . "</td><td>" . $exibe["dt_criacao_ambiente"] . "</td><td>" . $exibe["dt_last_update_ambiente"] . "</td><td>" . $nome_user . "</td></tr>";
  }
  echo "</tbody>"
        . "</table>"
        . "</div>";
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Passe só as linhas no loop

```
<div class="container" id="container">
    <h2>Ambientes Monitorados de <?php echo $nome_equipe?></h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Ambiente</th>
          <th>Solução</th>
          <th>Criação</th>
          <th>Ultima Atualização</th>
          <th>Criador</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
 <tbody>
  <?php $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nome_ambiente, solucao_ambiente, dt_criacao_ambiente, dt_last_update_ambiente, nome_equipe FROM tb_ambientes LEFT JOIN tb_equipes ON tb_ambientes.id_equipe = tb_equipes.id_equipe WHERE id_user = '$id_user'");
    while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  echo "<tr><td>" . $exibe["nome_ambiente"] . "</td><td>" . $exibe["solucao_ambiente"] . "</td><td>" . $exibe["dt_criacao_ambiente"] . "</td><td>" . $exibe["dt_last_update_ambiente"] . "</td><td>" . $nome_user . "</td></tr>";
  }

  ?>
  </tbody>
 </table>"
</div>
```